# How to get "damFolderPath" from a Node in AEM?

Tags: aem, jcr, sling

I'm using AEM 6.2 and trying to get the "damFolderPath" value from a Node's "jcr:content".

[image: Screenshot]

i tried these:

```
//resourcePath = "/content/projects/newyear-1"
Resource resource = resourceResolver.getResource(resourcePath);
Node tNode = resource.adaptTo(Node.class);
Property prop = tNode.getProperty("jcr:content/damFolderPath");
log.info("\n...Output 1:"+tNode.hasProperty("damFolderPath"));
log.info("\n...Output 2:"+prop.toString());
```

Output 1: false

Output 2: Property[PropertyDelegate{parent=/content/projects/newyear-1/kms/jcr:content: { jcr:primaryType = nt:unstructured, detailsHref = /projects/details.html, jcr:title = kms, active = true, cq:template = /apps/swa/projects/templates/default, **damFolderPath = /content/dam/projects/newyear-1/kms,** coverUrl = /content/dam/projects/newyear-1/kms/cover, sling:resourceType = cq/gui/components/projects/admin/card/projectcontent, links = { ... }, dashboard = { ... }}, **property=damFolderPath = /content/dam/projects/newyear-1/kms**}]

I can see it is there, but how do i get it from output2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the value without going as low as the JCR API level.

From Sling's point of view, `jcr:content` is a resolvable Resource.

```
String resourcePath = "/content/projects/newyear-1/jcr:content"
Resource jcrContentResource = resourceResolver.getResource(resourcePath);
ValueMap valueMap = jcrContentResource.getValueMap();
String damFolderPath = valueMap.get("damFolderPath", String.class);
```

If, for whatever reason, you insist on using the JCR API, the thing you see in *Output 2* is a default `String` representation of a `Property` implementation (as returned by `toString()`).

The [`Property`](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Property.html) interface allows you to obtain the property's value by using one of multiple, type-specific getters.

```
prop.getString()
```

will get you the path `/content/dam/projects/newyear-1`

See also: `getValue`, `getDouble`, `getBoolean`, `getDate`, etc.